# Probability of taken counters

Tags: probability

There are only red counters, blue counters and purple counters in a bag. The ratio of the number of red counters to the number blue counters is 3:17

Sam takes at random a counter from the bag.
The probability that the counter is purple is 0.2

Work out the probability that Same takes a red counter.

---

$P(purple)=\frac{1}{5}$

Ratio of red:blue:purple=3:17:purple

I have a problem in finding the total number of ball.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You don't need the total. $P({\rm red})=P({\rm not\ purple})P(\rm {red} |{\rm not\ purple})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r,b,p$ be the numbers of red, blue and purple counters (or balls), respectively. Also, let $N=r+b+p$. The given conditions:
$$\frac rb=\frac3{17} \Rightarrow b=\frac{17}3r;\\
\frac pN=0.2 \Rightarrow p=0.2N;\\
$$
Hence:
$$r+\frac{17}3r+0.2N=N \Rightarrow \frac{20}3r=0.8N \Rightarrow \frac rN=\frac3{25}=0.12.$$
You can not find the total number of counters, because only proportions are given (not enough information):
$$\begin{cases}p=0.2N\\ r+b+0.2N=N\\ \frac rb=\frac{3}{17}\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} p=0.2N\\ b=0.68N\\ r=0.12N\end{cases}$$